# PHP not displaying data from function

Tags: php

I am trying to make a call to the database so it displays a list with certain information, but for some reason it isn't working even though the same code was working before with other database.

It displays the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function displayLabs() in C:\wamp\www\MyFirstProyect\labs.php on line 258

This is the code:

```
 function getLabs(){
$query = "SELECT bk.idlab , bk.capacidad, bk.carrera, bk.ubicacion FROM labs as bk";

$result = do_query($query);

   return $result;
 }

 function displayLabs(){

$labs = getLabs();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($labs)){
echo '<ul>' .
        '<li>"Nombre: "' . $row['idlab'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>"Capacidad: "' . $row['capacidad'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>"Carrera: "' . $row['carrera'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>"Ubicación: "' . $row['ubicacion'] . '</li>' .
     '</ul>';
    }

}
```

Just in case this is html:

```
    <div class="popUp1" id="popUpCorrecto1">
        <div class="estiloPopUp">
          <span>Información de laboratorio</span>
          <span value="Cerrar" id="btnCerrar">x</span>
        </div>
            <?php displayLabs() ?>

          <input type = "button" value = "Eliminar" id = "btnEliminar" onclick="window.location='labEliminado.html';" />
          <input type = "button" value = "Modificar" id = "btnModificar"      onclick="window.location='modificarLab.html';" />

        </div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Something Mr.Fred told me gave me an idea and it worked, now it is displaying the information, BUT not of just one "Lab" But all of them XD So with the 4 test labs I entered into the database it is making 5 lists.

I guess I need to figure some kind of filter.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, HTML or SQL (jQuery isn't even mentioned?). The error tells you, the function isn't declared. If it worked on your previous setup, it's the path to where you're including the functions, most likely.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I am kinda distracted for being stuck with this error for a couple of hours now...

Comment: *"Just in case this is html:"* --- what's that file extension set as, `.php`? `.html`? I see two file references `labEliminado.html` and `modificarLab.html` if you're trying to run PHP in those, it won't work, unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` as PHP. Also, if your `displayLabs()` is inside another file besides your first body of code, then that's the reason why.

Comment: If your functions are in a separate file than the one mentioned in the error, the path to that included file needs to be checked. The path often changes between systems.

Comment: looks like you forgot a semicolon <?php displayLabs() ?>, or am I wrong?

Comment: The extension is .php the other in the onclick there were for testing, as for the code it is on another file but I am using:
<?php
   require_once 'includes/functionsLabs.php';
?>

Comment: Well, for one thing, the error above is generated by a Windows OS, so the slashes are all going to be wrong.

Comment: *"EDIT: Something Mr.Fred told me gave me an idea and it worked,"* --- being [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975155/php-not-displaying-data-from-function#comment35083958_22975155)?

Comment: It is working now, I opened Jared's profile and his intense gaze made me realize the error of my way (typo) that couple with Fred's suggestion. Now I am thinking of a way to filter it to diplay just the  infor of the lab I want and not EVERY damn...one...

Comment: I...I kinda wrote  <?php require_once 'includes/functionsLabs.pjp'; ?> and when I replied to you and copied/pasted the one you see above from another file I saw my mistake >.>

Comment: Ok, problem solved then. When replying to someone in particular, including the `@` symbol followed by the person's name, so he/she will receive notification.

Comment: @ Fred -ii-Thanks, you guys are the best (and the community here in general). It has made my first steps into the programming world more easy to endure.

Comment: You're welcome @CodeGrasshopper Would you like me to make [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975155/php-not-displaying-data-from-function#comment35083958_22975155) an answer to close the question? Not obligated.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- That would be much appreciated.

Comment: It has been done. Glad to have been of help @CodeGrasshopper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's request, [`comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975155/php-not-displaying-data-from-function#comment35083958_22975155) to answer. *(to close the question)*

*"Just in case this is html:"* --- what's that file extension set as, `.php`? `.html`?

I see two file references `labEliminado.html` and `modificarLab.html` if you're trying to run PHP in those, it won't work, unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` as PHP.

Also, if your `displayLabs()` is inside another file besides your first body of code, then that's the reason why.